# How to display information with a table using MS database (ASP.NET Core MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, sqlite, asp.net-identity

I created this project where it has a register and login page using identity. I followed this video for it. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzRM-hOe35o

I wanted to test an idea out, so I wanted to display the user information I have in my database. However, the only way I figured out how to display information is using the user manager option (@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.FirstName) in the _LoginPartial.cshtml file. In my journey to learn more, I came across this video teaching you how to display information from a database with a table. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wLfTRx2-FI

I have some problems, he is using Sqlite and I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18. I tried following the same way he did it with adding a list into the home controller. But, it didn't work the same way he did it

How do I adapt in order to use his way of displaying information from a database? Or is there an easier way to display information?

Here is my code. If you need anymore information just let me know

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Home Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Areas.Identity.Data;
using The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Model that's located in Areas>Identity>Data folder

CardinalUser.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the CardinalUser class
    public class CardinalUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(100)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(500)")]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string LoginName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
        public string SSN { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "int")]
        public int AccountBalance { get; set; }








    }
}
```

CardinalDbContext also located in the same folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Data
{
    public class CardinalDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CardinalUser>
    {
        public CardinalDbContext(DbContextOptions<CardinalDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Areas.Identity.Data

@inject SignInManager<CardinalUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<CardinalUser> UserManager


<ul class="navbar-nav">

    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="manage" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.FirstName @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.LastName Balance: $@UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.AccountBalance </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                <button id="logout" type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="register" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside Startup.cs there's a ConfigureService method. Add your db context to the SQL provider there: services.AddDbContext<CardinalDBContext>(o => { o.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString"); });

Comment: I can see that you have codes in the _LoginPartial.cshtml to display user information. Are you getting any error or the output is not showing up?

Comment: @rahatur I'm getting information from the signed-in user. But I want to display everything from the database. Not just from the signed-in user

Comment: FirstName, LAstName, Balance coming from the database right?

Comment: @Rahatur Yes they are

Comment: So you want to list all the users from the database? Then please check the answer I have written.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<User> allusers = await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync();
```

Now enumarate the list of Users and render the data

```
foreach(User u in allusers)
{
    u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName + " " + u.AccountBalance + "<br/>"
}
```

Comment: where would i put this at

Comment: Where you want the list of user info to show up. In the UI why dont you put this in the _LoginPartial.cshtml right after the `<ul class="navbar-nav">` line?